# Defining a function in R with if-statements

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I want to create a new column, `DELAY_CAUSE`. This column needs to contain `NA` if `ARR_DELAY` is 0 or lower; `"KNOWN"` if the sum of `CARRIER_DELAY`, `WEATHER_DELAY`, `SECURITY_DELAY` and `LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY` is at least equal to `ARRIVAL_DELAY`, and `"UNKNOWN"` otherwise.

My code is:

```
delay_reason <- function() {
  if ARR_DELAY <= 0 {
    return("NA")
  } else if(sum(CARRIER_DELAY, WEATHER_DELAY, SECURITY_DELAY, LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY) >= ARRIVAL_DELAY) {
    return("KNOWN")
  } else {
    return("UNKNOWN")
  }
}

df_flights$CAUSE_DELAY <- delay_reason
```

However, I get two errors:

first:

`Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level`

second:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
```

How can I fix that my function works?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use subsetting in some way(use your logicals to subset).Otherwise, probably is a mismatched `(` or `{`. The function also doesn't know your variables so I suggest you rewrite it with a data parameter supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ifelse` function for a vectorized solution:

```
df$delay_reason <- ifelse(df$ARR_DELAY <= 0, "NA",
                       ifelse(df$CARRIER_DELAY + df$WEATHER_DELAY + df$SECURITY_DELAY +
                           df$LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY >= df$ARRIVAL_DELAY, "KNOWN", "UNKNOWN"))
```